# get error code from called devenv.exe in jenkins pipeline

Tags: groovy, cmd, jenkins-pipeline

I just try to erase all Freestyle Jobs from our Jenkins Server. Therefore I call our VS builds directly from the Pipeline job:

```
bat """chcp 1252 & "PATHTOVS\\devenv.com" /rebuild Release^|$buildBranch $WORKSPACE\\SOLUTION.sln >> ${buildBranch}_$CPNUM_PARAM.txt"""
```

Now I am wondering how to differentieate between the three Build States (SUCCESS/UNSTABLE/FAILED). Until now I am using a `try/catch` block. But this isnt very clean and also does not provides the UNStABLE state.

```
try{
    #buildcall
    state = 'SUCCESS'
}catch(e){
    state = 'FAILED'
}
```

Unfortuantely I am not sure which error codes from `devenv.exe` can be retrieved and how to perform this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it the following way:

```
try{
    //do something
    }
}catch(e){
    String error = "${e}"
    println error
}
```